# Can you turn this sum of trig functions into one sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone give me a term involving a single sum for the below? Or some kind of simplification? I need to integrate the answer.

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}\beta^{n}(a+b)^{2n}\cos^{2n}(x)}{n!}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}\beta^{n}(a+b)^{2n}\sin^{2n}(x)}{n!}\right)$$

Any help?

Alex

Comment: Hint: $(-1)^n\beta^n(a+b)^{2n}\cos^{2n}(x)=\left(-\beta(a+b)^2\cos^{2}(x)\right)^n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you gave no indication about what you tried and where you are stuck, here is a hint:
$$
\exp\left(-\beta(a+b)^2\cos^2(x)\right)\cdot\exp\left(-\beta(a+b)^2\sin^2(x)\right)=\exp\left(-\beta(a+b)^2\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks for this I got it - sorry about the poor question I rushed in, showing folly.